# Extracting helper static methods into objec

Tags: scala, object

I have some class:

```
class MyActor extends Actor{

    override def receive: Receive = {
        case s: String => doSome()
        case i: Int => //something else
    }

}

object MyActor{
    def doSome() = //some action
}
```

Is it an idiomatic way in Scala? I did that to simplify testing the `Actor`. I dont want to create `ActorSystem` and write integration test in my specific case.

Is it common to do so?

Comment: If the point is testing `MyActor.doSome()` in isolation - looks fine to me so I wonder what Jon has on his mind when proposing `trait`. But I think it's still important to do integration testing of actors with akka-testkit to verify state transitions / FSM.

Comment: Using `object`s can make testing more difficult.  For example, if you wanted to unit test the actual Actor itself, there would not be a way to mock or stub out the `doSome` method, because the actor is depending on a specific implementation of it.

Answer (score 2):

No, the idiomatic way is to extract those methods into a trait, and have the actor extend that trait:

```
trait DoSomething {
   def doSome() = {
      println("Doing something")
   }
}

class MyActor extends Actor with DoSomething {
    override def receive: Receive = {
        case s: String => doSome()
        case i: Int => //something else
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you provide implementation of `DoSomething` for `MyActor`? If simply by implementing `doSome()` - I don't see the difference.

Comment: The implementation would be in the trait